# MediaStorage.Images.Thumbnails is deprecated in API29. How to use the loadThumbnail()?

Tags: java, android

```
Bitmap miniThumb = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr,id,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Comment: the path as in path in retrieving the bitmap?

Comment: the path of your complete media file

Comment: oops sry just give me 5 minutes i will give you answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use it by checking the SDK version first.
If you queried for media, the `mediaUri` will be constructed by appending the media ID to the content URI, e.g. `mediaUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(imagesContentUri, id)`

```
val thumbnail = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    val cs = CancellationSignal()
    context.contentResolver.loadThumbnail(mediaUri, Size(100, 100), cs)
} else {
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(context.contentResolver, id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaMetaDataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetaDataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource("path of your file");  //===========Other Options also available
byte[] data = mmr.getEmbededPicture();
if(data!=null){
    //========Create Bitmap with byte array======//
}else{
    //========Do your code if media has no image====//
}
```